# Gruntfile.js with "require" function and passing parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization, gruntjs

I have a Grunt file (`Gruntfile.js`) to build an angularjs component. I use an external javascript file (`build.config.js`) to define the required files and output directories.

```
module.exports = {
    build_dir: 'build',
    app_files: {
        src: ['src/**/*.js','!src/**/*.spec.js'],
        //...
    },
    vendor_files: {
        js: [ /* vendor files like jquery, bootstrap, etc... */ ]
    }
}
```

And my Gruntfile.js calling it like this

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    /* some code */
    var userConfig = require('./build.config.js');
    var taskConfig = {
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json"),
        /* more code */
    },
    /* yet more code */
}
```

In my package.json, I specify a `locale` variable for i18n purposes that I can use inside the `taskConfig` section by putting it like `'<%= pkg.locale %>'`.  Now there are some javascript files specified in `build.config.js` that I need to load depending on the locale specified, but I don't know how to get this variable since in `build.config.js` there is no `grunt` object to read the `package.json` file.  Therefore, I can't do something like this in `build.config.js`:

```
vendor_files: {
    js: [ 'vendor/foo/bar.<%= pkg.locale %>.js' ]
```

Is there any way I can accomplish this without putting everything from `build.config.js` back in `Gruntfile.js`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Grunt templates just point to the Grunt config itself.

So for the config:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: {
    locale: 'en'
  }
});
```

A template `<%= pkg.locale %>` will equal the string `'en'`.

`pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json")` just reads your `package.json` file as javascript object and assigns to the `pkg` property in your config.

You're free to build that config object however you wish, either declaratively, read/parse JSON files, or `require` other scripts which export a javascript object (as what `./build.config.js` appears to do).

Also consider `grunt.config('pkg.locale', 'en');` for overriding single config values after you have init your config: http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config